# Event Handling Swing components

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to learn Java bit by bit, recreating an application I completed in Python - a library control software, very basic. I am having problems, though, with Event Handling, primarily because (I think) I went full-blown in to Swing without knowing much about it, but figuring it out as I went.

Here's my code, so far:

```
public class SEHBV extends JFrame{

    public SEHBV(){

        super("SEHBV Biblio 2.0");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("books.ico");
        setIconImage(img.getImage());

        JPanel p_ini, locar, devolver, buscar, administrar;
        JLabel l_dia, l_mes, l_ano, loca_cs, loca_cl, loca_prazo, loca_cb, locado_state;
        JTextField dia, mes, ano, loca_cs_tf, loca_cl_tf, loca_prazo_tf, loca_cb_tf, devolve_cod;
        JTextArea loca_prazo_data, loca_oper_res, mostra_multa;
        JButton data, loca_cb_bt, loca_commit, ver_multa;
        JList<String> loca_s_res, loca_cb_res, atrasos, locados;


        p_ini = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints i = new GridBagConstraints();
        l_dia = new JLabel("Dia: ");
        l_mes = new JLabel("Mês: ");
        l_ano = new JLabel("Ano: ");
        dia = new JTextField(6);
        mes = new JTextField(6);
        ano = new JTextField(6);
        data = new JButton("Afirmar Data");
        atrasos = new JList<String>();  
        atrasos.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        atrasos.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        atrasos.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        JScrollPane scroll_atrasos = new JScrollPane(atrasos);
        atrasos.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        atrasos.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));

        i.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        i.gridx = 0;
        i.gridy = 0;
        p_ini.add(l_dia, i);
        i.gridx = 1;
        p_ini.add(dia, i);
        i.gridx = 2;
        p_ini.add(l_mes, i);
        i.gridx = 3;
        p_ini.add(mes, i);
        i.gridx = 4;
        p_ini.add(l_ano, i);
        i.gridx = 5;
        p_ini.add(ano, i);
        i.gridx = 6;
        p_ini.add(data, i);
        i.gridy = 1;
        i.gridx = 0;
        i.gridwidth = 7;
        p_ini.add(scroll_atrasos, i);

        //GUI Locação 
        locar = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints l = new GridBagConstraints();
        l.gridx = 0;
        l.gridy = 0;
        JPanel loca_socios = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel loca_oper = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints o = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel loca_busca = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints b = new GridBagConstraints();


        locar.add(loca_socios, l); //Busca de Sócios na janela de Locação

        loca_s_res = new JList<String>();
        loca_s_res.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        loca_s_res.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        loca_s_res.setModel(Runner.nome_socios);
        loca_s_res.setVisibleRowCount(25);
        JScrollPane scroll_loca_s = new JScrollPane(loca_s_res);
        loca_s_res.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
        loca_socios.add(scroll_loca_s);

        l.gridx = 1;
        locar.add(loca_oper, l); //Locação propriamente dita
        o.weighty = 1;
        o.weightx = 1;
        o.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        o.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);
        loca_cs = new JLabel("Código do Sócio: ");
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        o.gridx = 0;
        o.gridy = 0;
        loca_oper.add(loca_cs, o);

        loca_cs_tf = new JTextField(5);
        loca_cs_tf.setEditable(false);
        loca_cs_tf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        o.gridx = 1;
        o.gridy = 0;
        loca_oper.add(loca_cs_tf, o);

        loca_cl = new JLabel("Código do Livro: ");
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        o.gridx = 0;
        o.gridy = 1;
        loca_oper.add(loca_cl, o);

        loca_cl_tf = new JTextField(5);
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        o.gridx = 1;
        o.gridy = 1;
        loca_oper.add(loca_cl_tf, o);

        loca_prazo = new JLabel("Prazo para devolução (em dias): ");
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        o.gridx = 0;
        o.gridy = 2;
        loca_oper.add(loca_prazo, o);

        loca_prazo_tf = new JTextField(5);
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        o.gridx = 1;
        o.gridy = 2;
        loca_oper.add(loca_prazo_tf, o);

        loca_prazo_data = new JTextArea();
        loca_prazo_data.setBackground(getForeground());
        o.gridx = 0;
        o.gridy = 3;
        o.gridwidth = 3;
        loca_oper.add(loca_prazo_data, o);

        loca_commit = new JButton("Realizar Locação");
        o.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        o.gridx = 0;
        o.gridy = 4;
        o.gridwidth = 3;
        loca_oper.add(loca_commit, o);


        loca_oper_res = new JTextArea();
        loca_oper_res.setBackground(getForeground());
        o.gridy = 5;
        loca_oper.add(loca_oper_res, o);

        l.gridx = 2;
        locar.add(loca_busca, l);
        loca_cb = new JLabel("Chave de Busca: ");
        b.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        b.gridx = 0;
        b.gridy = 0;
        loca_busca.add(loca_cb, b);

        loca_cb_tf = new JTextField(20);
        b.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        b.gridx = 1;
        b.gridy = 0;
        loca_busca.add(loca_cb_tf, b);

        loca_cb_bt = new JButton("Busca Rápida");
        b.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        b.gridx = 2;
        b.gridy = 0;
        loca_busca.add(loca_cb_bt, b);

        loca_cb_res = new JList<String>();
        loca_cb_res.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        loca_cb_res.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        b.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        loca_cb_res.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
        b.gridx = 0;
        b.gridy = 1;
        b.gridwidth = 3;
        b.gridheight = 2;
        loca_cb_res.setVisibleRowCount(25);
        JScrollPane scroll_loca_cb = new JScrollPane(loca_cb_res);
        loca_cb_res.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
        loca_busca.add(scroll_loca_cb, b);


    // Other Tabs of the GUI


    //GUI Geral
    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();

    tp.addTab("Página inicial (Alt+I)", null, p_ini, "pág. inicial");
    tp.addTab("Locação (Alt+L)", locar);
    tp.addTab("Devolução (Alt+D)", devolver);
    tp.addTab("Busca Avançada (Alt+B)", buscar);
    tp.addTab("Administração (Alt+A)", administrar);
    tp.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_I);
    tp.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_L);
    tp.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_D);
    tp.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_B);
    tp.setMnemonicAt(4, KeyEvent.VK_A);

    add(tp);
}
```

So, lets say I'm trying to handle the clicking of the `loca_commit JButton`. I'm trying to create an Event Handler - according to Java tutorials and other StackOverflow questions/answers - but the handler does not identify `loca_commit`. Right now I'm just trying to get it to work, then I'll use it for calling a method, but if I can't make it create a pop up, well, you get my point.

So, my code for the handler so far is this:

```
    private class LocaHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            String string = "";

            if(event.getSource()==loca_commit)
                string=String.format("Botão Apertado");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
        }
```

Can you guys shed a light here?

Comment: BTW, the main so far is just sizing and making the frame visible, real basic.

Comment: Note: when trying to figure out how to add an action listener to a button, the example requires one button and one action listener, as opposed to 4 buttons, 3 text areas, a bunch of labels & text fields, 3 lists, an image icon.. *"BTW, the main so far is just sizing and making the frame visible"* So we'd need to change it before compiling & trying the code. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It should include a `main` method and the imports, but leave as many of the other components out, as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is probably one of context, the `LocaHandler` probably doesn't have any context to `SEHBV` or the `loca_commit` button, so you can't reference it (it's out of context).

There are couple of ways you might fix this...

## You could...

Pass a reference of `loca_commit` to the instance of `LocaHandler`, but unless you intended to make use of `LocaHandler` to handle multiple actions, it really doesn't make sense, which means...

## You could...

Make `LocaHandler` responsible for only doing one thing, what ever `loca_commit` needs it to.  This leads you into the realm of the [Actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

How ever...

## You could...

Make use of the `actionCommand` property support of `JButton` and `ActionEvent`

```
loca_commit = new JButton("Realizar Locação");
loca_commit.setActionCommand("locaCommit");

//...

private class LocaHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String string = "";

        if("locaCommit".equals(event.getActionCommand()))
            string=String.format("Botão Apertado");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
}
```

This means that you could use the same instance of `LocaHandler` to handle multiple commands (by expanding the `if` statement)

My personal preference is to use the Actions API or anonymous classes, focusing on the handlers to a single responsibility, if done well, it will increase the reusability of the classes

Comment: Thank you, the third solution should work. Each JPanel (each tab) executes multiple functions, so it is optimal for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way of making it work is to attach action listener on button after initializing it. In your case, try the following:

```
loca_commit = new JButton("Realizar Locação");
//other code

loca_commit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
      }
});
loca_oper.add(loca_commit, o);
```

Remember, this is just one way of doing it. There are multiple other ways to achieve the same result.